# UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview

how to understand that view is fully loaded?

Comment: How can a view be partially loaded?

Comment: He wants to know how to tell if his view comes with chili and cheese on top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view is fully loaded by the time your [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `viewDidLoad` method is called.

You can also use the `isViewLoaded` method to determine if the view is currently loaded in memory.

Hmm... can't help but think that's not what you're trying to ask, but that's what you appear to have asked. These are exciting times.

Answer (score 1):

Check `UIViewController`'s `-isViewLoaded` method.